# Months in gnuplot

Tags: bash, awk, gnuplot, paste

I have a csv file with 12 numbers which correspond to the 12 months. An example of the file is as follows:

```
$ cat data.csv
"3","5","6","5","4","6","7","6","4","4","3","3",
```

I'd like to plot these with the months in the x-axis using "January, February, March and so on."

I've found this script but I don't know how to input the months:

```
for FILE in data.csv; do
 gnuplot -p << EOF
 set datafile separator ","
 set xlabel "xlabel"
 set ylabel "ylabel"
 set title "graphTitle"
 plot "$FILE" using $xcolumn:$ycolumn
  EOF
done
```

The expected output should be a plot where the x-axis is the month and the y-axis is the data from the csv file.
Note that in the CSV file there aren't the months, just the numbers. That's why I am asking what is the best way to achieve this without having to enter them manually in the CSV or looping through an array. Is there any gnuplot function that adds the date and can be formatted?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide a sample of `data.csv`?  as for the names of the months ... what would a data file look like if it had the names of the months and the numeric data (ie, what format could `gnuplot` read as x/y coordinates)? ... I'm wondering what (coding) options might be available to auto-generate the names of the months, but would need to know a valid format that `gnuplot` can read

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, a sample of data.csv is already in the question. I've copied the exact content of the data.csv. This is `"3","5","6","5","4","6","7","6","4","4","3","3",`

Comment: ok, so you know that `for FILE in data.csv` loops once with `FILE=data.csv`, right?

Comment: Yep, I know that and I need it for the $x variable. However I don't know how to output the months following this logic.

Comment: assuming you're not running under some 'weird' locale you can auto-generate the months via `locale mon` ... included in my answer (below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: After reviewing OPs post and code some more, I'm *guessing* the desired format looks like:

```
January:"3",February:"5",March:"6",April:"5",May:"4",June:"6",July:"7",August:"6",September:"4",October:"4",November:"3",December:"3",
```

If this is the case, we can use the same solution (below) and pipe the final results through `tr` to transpose the data back to a single-line/multi-column dataset, eg:

```
$ paste -d" " <(locale mon | tr ';' '\n') <(tr ',' '\n' < data.csv) | grep -v '^ $' | tr ' \n' ':,'
January:"3",February:"5",March:"6",April:"5",May:"4",June:"6",July:"7",August:"6",September:"4",October:"4",November:"3",December:"3",
```

And updating OPs code:

```
datfile=$(mktemp)
for FILE in data.csv
do
    paste -d" " <(locale mon | tr ';' '\n') <(tr ',' '\n' < data.csv) | grep -v '^ $' | tr ' \n' ':,' > "${datfile}"

    gnuplot -p <<-EOF
    set datafile separator ","
    set xlabel "xlabel"
    set ylabel "ylabel"
    set title "graphTitle"
    plot "${datfile}" using $xcolumn:$ycolumn
    EOF
done
'rm' -rf "${datfile}" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

---

Looks like `gnuplot` can accept data in various formats, including the following:

```
January "3"
February "5"
March "6"
April "5"
May "4"
June "6"
July "7"
August "6"
September "4"
October "4"
November "3"
December "3"
```

**NOTE**: If OP determines this is not an acceptable file format then I'm sure we can come up with something else ... would just need the question updated with a sample of a valid file format showing months and numerics.

So if we can generate this data set on the fly we could then feed it to `gnuplot` ...

First we'll let `locale` generate the months for us:

```
$ locale mon
January;February;March;April;May;June;July;August;September;October;November;December
```

Next we can transpose our single-line/multi-column datasets to multi-line/single-column datasets:

```
$ locale mon | tr ';' '\n'
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December

$ tr ',' '\n' < data.csv
"3"
"5"
"6"
"5"
"4"
"6"
"7"
"6"
"4"
"4"
"3"
"3"
```

From here we can `paste` these 2 datasets together, using a space as the column delimiter:

```
$ paste -d" " <(locale mon | tr ';' '\n') <(tr ',' '\n' < data.csv)
January "3"
February "5"
March "6"
April "5"
May "4"
June "6"
July "7"
August "6"
September "4"
October "4"
November "3"
December "3"
```

One last step would be to write this to a (tmp) file, eg:

```
$ datfile=$(mktemp)
$ paste -d" " <(locale mon | tr ';' '\n') <(tr ',' '\n' < data.csv) | grep -v '^ $' > "${datfile}"
$ cat "${datfile}"
January "3"
February "5"
March "6"
April "5"
May "4"
June "6"
July "7"
August "6"
September "4"
October "4"
November "3"
December "3"
```

**NOTE**: The `grep -v '^ $'` is to get rid of the extra line at the end related to the last comma (`,`) in `data.csv`

From here `"${datfile}"` can be fed to `gnuplot` as needed and once no longer needed deleted, eg:

```
$ gnuplot ... "${datfile}" ...
$ 'rm' -rf "${datfile}" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Hi  @markp-fuso thank you so much for your detailed answer. It makes sense to me however when running it I got the following error: `gnuplot> plot "/tmp/tmp.CSHtJEV8sR" using : line 0: constant expression required` and I can't run it. I've even output the result of $d{datfile} and looks fine to me. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not a `gnuplot` user ... my answer was focused solely on trying to build a valid input/data file - which in turn was based on guesses of what formats would be valid; net result ... without more details (eg, exact content of your `${datfile}` file, values of the `$xcolumn` and `$ycolumn` variables, and the entire `gnuplot` command being run) ... I'm not going to be of much help

Answer (score 3):

If you do not mind typing in the month names, I think the simplest is this. Data is shown in-line for clarity rather than reading from a file.

```
$DATA << EOD
"3","5","6","5","4","6","7","6","4","4","3","3",
EOD

set datafile sep comma
set xrange [0:13]
unset key

array Month[12] = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

plot for [N=1:12] $DATA using (N):(column(N)):xticlabel(Month[N]) with impulse lw 5
```

[image]

If you do not want to type in the month names, the following should generate the equivalent. `"%b"` will generate the abbreviated month names as above. `"%B"`would generate the full month name.

```
Month(i) = strftime("%b", i * 3600.*24.*28.)
plot for [N=1:12] $DATA using (N):(column(N)):xticlabel(Month(N)) with impulse lw 5
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the loop syntax, there is a way to read your CSV file as a 1x12 matrix. Also, for long month names, you can use gnuplot's strftime function by giving it the format specifier "%B".

The gnuplot script is here.

```
set key noautotitle
set datafile separator comma
set yrange [0:10]
set xrange [-1:12]
set xtics rotate by -45
set grid xtics

# This function generates the names "January", "February", ... 
#                from the integer value 0, 1, ...
#
monthname(i) = strftime("%B",strptime("%m",sprintf("%i",i+1)))

# `matrix every ...` specifier tells to read the data as a 1x12 matrix.
#
plot "data.csv" matrix every :::0:11:0 using 1:3:xtic(monthname($1)) with linespoints pt 7
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution. Because you have a trailing comma and gnuplot expects a number after it, you will get a warning `warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values` which you can ignore. Therefore, you should limit the x-maximum to smaller 12.
In your case, replace `$Data` with your filename `'data.csv'`. You might want to set another locale (check `help locale`) to get other languages for the months' names.

**Code:**

```
### plot monthly data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
"3","5","6","5","4","6","7","6","4","4","3","3",
EOD

set datafile separator comma
set boxwidth 0.8
set style fill solid 0.5
set yrange[0:10]
set xrange[-0.9:11.9]
myMonth(i) = strftime("%b",i*3600*24*31)   # get month name as abbreviation, use %B for full name

plot $Data matrix u 1:0:xtic(myMonth($1)) w boxes title "my data"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` solution built around the same logic as the `paste` answer, but which eliminates a few sub-processes (eg, `grep`, multiple `tr's`) ...

```
awk -F'[;,]' '                             # input field delimiters are ";" and ","
BEGIN   { OFS=":" ; ORS="," }              # set output field delimiter as ":" and output record delimiter as ","
FNR==NR { for (i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++)          # loop through fields from first file ...
          month[i]=$(i)                    # store in our month[] array
          next                             # skip to next input line
        }
        { for (i=1 ; i< NF ; i++)          # loop through fields from second file ...
          print month[i],$(i)              # print month and current field
        }
' <(locale mon) data.csv
```

This generates:

```
January:"3",February:"5",March:"6",April:"5",May:"4",June:"6",July:"7",August:"6",September:"4",October:"4",November:"3",December:"3",
```

Rolling this into OP's code:

```
datfile=$(mktemp)
for FILE in data.csv
do
    awk -F'[;,]' 'BEGIN{OFS=":";ORS=","} FNR==NR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) mon[i]=$(i); next} {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print mon[i],$(i)}' <(locale mon) data.csv > "${datfile}"

    gnuplot -p <<-EOF
    set datafile separator ","
    set xlabel "xlabel"
    set ylabel "ylabel"
    set title "graphTitle"
    plot "${datfile}" using $xcolumn:$ycolumn
    EOF
done
'rm' -rf "${datfile}" > /dev/null 2>&1
```